# Python: How can I increase index for a list in a dictionary?

Tags: python

```
mydict = {}
pop_bin_dict = {}

pop_bin_holder = []

new = []
index = 0


file_handle = open(filename, 'r')

for line in file_handle:
    line = line.rstrip()
    line = line.split(',')
    mydict[line[0]] = int(line[1]) # first dict
    
print(mydict) # result: {'St. Martin (French part)': 31949, 'Nauru': 13049, 'Palau': 21503, 'British Virgin Islands': 30661, 'San Marino': 33203, 'Gibraltar': 34408, 'Monaco': 38499, 'Turks and Caicos Islands': 34900, 'Liechtenstein': 37666}

for key in mydict:
    pop_bin = mydict[key] // granularity
    if pop_bin not in pop_bin_holder:
        pop_bin_holder.append(pop_bin)


print(pop_bin_holder) # result = [3, 1, 2]

# below i'm trying out a few things, it's incorrect but it's the closest ive got

for key in mydict:
    pop_bin = mydict[key] // granularity
    if pop_bin == pop_bin_holder[index]:
        new.append(key)
        pop_bin_dict[pop_bin_holder[index]] = new
index += 1



print(pop_bin_dict) # prints out: {3: ['St. Martin (French part)', 'British Virgin Islands', 'San Marino', 'Gibraltar', 'Monaco', 'Turks and Caicos Islands', 'Liechtenstein']}
```

why isn't the `index += 1` increasing the `index` ? I am trying to get the last part of the code to be:

```py
{3: ['St. Martin (French part)', 'British Virgin Islands', 'San Marino', 'Gibraltar', 'Monaco', 'Turks and Caicos Islands', 'Liechtenstein'], 1: ['Nauru'], 2: ['Palau']}
```

Comment: `index` is dedented, so it only executes once, after the loop is done. Did you mean to include in the `for` or the `if` block?

Comment: no, i meant it to be an if, but really the end of the code is me experimenting

Comment: take a look at the `csv DictReader` class in the Python standard library. Looks like you're reinventing the wheel in the code block beginning `for line in file_handle`

Answer (score 1):

You're lacking an indentation: `index += 1` should be under the `for` loop, but it's after it as you've posted.

Looking at your code, you're only storing *unique* elements, not all of them, in `pop_bin_holder`. You will therefore have `len(pop_bin_holder) < len(mydict)` if you have at least one repeating `pop_bin`, therefore throwing an `IndexError`. You need to provide more details regarding that particular issue if that's now your question

Comment: if i put the 'index += 1' in any other indentation it will show an indexerror: list out of range

Answer (score 0):

`index` is not in the right indentation, it's outside the `for` loop.

Also, if you want to enumerate things that way, you'll want to use the `enumerate` function like so:

```
for (idx, (key, value)) in enumerate(mydict.items()):
    pass  # use idx, key, value in some way
```